# How to custom build a debuginfo package for rpm built from binaries?

Tags: package, rpm, rpmbuild, debug-information

I want to build my main rpm from binaries, not source, this is already done, but now I need to generate a debug-info rpm package to come with my main rpm

I want to do something as simple as

```
objcopy --debug-only mybinary => put that into mybinary-debuginfo.rpm
```

Is that possible with Rpmbuild?

Comment: Usually debug info is generated automatically and it shouldn't matter if your main RPM is built from binaries. As part of the build process, RPM will attempt to extract debug symbols from those binaries. If it doesn't, you might have disabled this behaviour in the spec file and/or there are no debug symbols in the binaries to begin with.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin So I have no option to control that? I've read that people have gotten away with custom `find-debuginfo.sh` but there is no documentation on how to use that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DanilaVershinin was right the binaries are stripped and the debug_info was packaged correctly (you can rely on them being stripped and debug_info separated if they are installed as binaries)

It was a tiny change that I had to put in my `.spec` file:

```
%define _debugsource_template %{nil}
```

It is not present in any documentation so might be unstable